# How to define variables properly in mathematica, a variable with two name

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

I wanted to define a variable in the name "beam_frequency", this is quite possible in other programming languages like python and Matlab. How to define two pair variable name in Mathematica as I defined above.

```
beam_frequency = 110
kk = beam_frequency/10
```

It is very difficult to deal with in Mathematica

Comment: `_` is a pattern object, that's why Mathematica doesnt allow symbolnames with `_` !

Comment: is there any alternative way to define the two pair variables?

Comment: You could omit `_` in the double name

Comment: start with a lowercase letter and capitalize the first character of the second word.

Comment: The format of @DanielHuber is pretty much the de facto standard. Mathematica's built-in symbols always have the "CamelCase" format (sometimes called "Pascal case"), and user-defined symbols then use the "camelCase" format to avoid possible collisions.

Comment: It is possible to enter _ as a character as well by using ESC _ ESC.

Comment: Maybe You can use: `beam$frequency = 110
kk = beam$frequency/10` , instead `_` ?